# How Can I Remove Decimal From Price in Magento 2.4.6?

Tags: magento2.4, price, shopping-cart-price-rules, currency, laminas

how can I remove the decimal section after the price in Magento 2.4.6 on the admin and frontend ?

Answer (score 0):

**Please follow the below steps to update the Price Format In Magento 2**

1. First of all you need to override the format class of magento
   (Magento\Framework\Locale\Format) for this, you need to write a line
   in etc/di.xml

2. Then override the function getPriceFormat in format class.

namespace Vendor\CustomPriceFormat\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Locale\Bundle\DataBundle;

class Format extends \Magento\Framework\Locale\Format
{
private static $defaultNumberSet = 'latn';

```
public function getPriceFormat($localeCode = null, $currencyCode = null)
{
    $localeCode = $localeCode ?: $this->_localeResolver->getLocale();
    if ($currencyCode) {
        $currency = $this->currencyFactory->create()->load($currencyCode);
    } else {
        $currency = $this->_scopeResolver->getScope()->getCurrentCurrency();
    }

    $localeData = (new DataBundle())->get($localeCode);
    $defaultSet = $localeData['NumberElements']['default'] ?: self::$defaultNumberSet;

    $format = $localeData['NumberElements'][$defaultSet]['patterns']['currencyFormat']
        ?: ($localeData['NumberElements'][self::$defaultNumberSet]['patterns']['currencyFormat']
            ?: explode(';', $localeData['NumberPatterns'][1])[0]);

    //your main changes are gone here.....
    $decimalSymbol = '.';
    $groupSymbol = ',';

    $pos = strpos($format, ';');
    if ($pos !== false) {
        $format = substr($format, 0, $pos);
    }
    $format = preg_replace("/[^0\#\.,]/", "", $format);
    $totalPrecision = 0;
    $decimalPoint = strpos($format, '.');
    if ($decimalPoint !== false) {
        $totalPrecision = strlen($format) - (strrpos($format, '.') + 1);
    } else {
        $decimalPoint = strlen($format);
    }
    $requiredPrecision = $totalPrecision;
    $t = substr($format, $decimalPoint);
    $pos = strpos($t, '#');
    if ($pos !== false) {
        $requiredPrecision = strlen($t) - $pos - $totalPrecision;
    }

    if (strrpos($format, ',') !== false) {
        $group = $decimalPoint - strrpos($format, ',') - 1;
    } else {
        $group = strrpos($format, '.');
    }
    $integerRequired = strpos($format, '.') - strpos($format, '0');

    $result = [
        //TODO: change interface
        'pattern' => $currency->getOutputFormat(),
        'precision' => $totalPrecision,
        'requiredPrecision' => $requiredPrecision,
        'decimalSymbol' => $decimalSymbol,
        'groupSymbol' => $groupSymbol,
        'groupLength' => $group,
        'integerRequired' => $integerRequired,
    ];       
    return $result;
}
```

}

Comment: my main problem with adminpanel 
how can i do it on adminpanel ?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to remove the decimal section after the price on the frontend:

1. Create a custom theme or use your existing theme. If you're using a custom theme, make sure it's a child theme of the parent theme you're using.
2. In your custom theme, navigate to the following directory:

   ```
   app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml
   ```

   If the `default.phtml` file does not exist in the above path, you may need to create it.
3. Open the `default.phtml` file in a text editor.
4. Find the line of code that looks like this:

   ```php
   <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->formatCurrency($block->getDisplayValue(), (bool)$block->getIncludeContainer()) ?>
   ```
5. Replace the above line with the following code to remove the decimal section:

   ```php
   <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ intval($block->getDisplayValue()) ?>
   ```

   The `intval()` function is used to convert the price to an integer, effectively removing the decimal section.
6. Save the file.
7. Clear the Magento cache by running the following command in the command line:

   ```bash
   bin/magento cache:flush
   ```

After following these steps, the decimal section should be removed from the price display on the frontend of your Magento store.

Please note that this customization affects the display of prices on the frontend only and does not impact the actual calculation or precision of the prices within the system.

Comment: Hi i need run it for frontend and adminpanel both of them